# Trouble connecting to LAN card (Lantronix Micro125)

Tags: network

I am having a tough time connecting to a LAN card (Lantronix Micro 125 'Embeded Device Server'). I can ping it, but the software I have to use to reset the card won't find it and the card doesn't show up as a connected device on my router.

My problem started when I changed my ISP. The card was connected directly to a cable modem with a static IP address, so it could be accessed from anywhere. Here's the old IP information the cable company provided me. The account is cancelled, so I'm not worried about publishing the info.

```
IP Addresses: 75.99.193.244
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.248
Default Gateway: 75.99.193.241
DNS Server #1: 167.206.112.138
DNS Server #2: 167.206.7.4
Assigned Subnet: 75.99.193.240
```

I can connect to the card directly from my laptop with a crossover cable (I set the IP address of the PC to 75.99.193.240) and I am able to interact with the card perfectly with the software I use to operate the system it's connected to. I also set up an old router with the IP address 75.99.193.1 and I am able to interact with the card perfectly through a PC connected to the same router. I can also ping it and telnet into it with either connection.

The problem is: the software I would use to reset the router doesn't find the card, whether I try through the router or with the crossover cable -- I can't even see the card on the router's list of connected devices. The software is Lantronix DeviceInstaller. I should also be able to access the card through a web browser, but that doesn't work either.

Here's the output of arp -a

```
Interface: 75.99.193.202 --- 0x8

  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type

  75.99.193.1           c8-3a-35-55-55-08     dynamic

  75.99.193.244         00-20-4a-d8-07-e1     dynamic

  75.99.193.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static

  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static

  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static

  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static

  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

I'm not too knowledgeable about this stuff, but I thought the problem might be the subnet mask. While connected with the crossover cable, I've tried subnet 255.255.255.0, 255.255.255.248 and several others -- the software still can't find the card.

Finally, this may not mean anything, but I could never connect to the card on the first try. I would always have to retry 1-3 times.

Any ideas?